# Playframework: JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I started to contribute to one Play project in Java, downloaded code, created Play project, added libraries and set all I could and then created database.
Finally everything seemed to be ok, but when i run localhost:9000 i get this error:

```
JPA error
@66kcmab39
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /favicon.ico

JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Unable to get the default  Bean Validation factory
play.exceptions.JPAException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:227)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:427)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:530)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:100)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:104)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:477)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyConstraintsToDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:429)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:403)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1459)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1086)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:225)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:95)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:322)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:83)
... 14 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:319)
... 15 more
```

Play version: 1.1.1
MySQL5
OS Ubuntu

Any idea what can be wrong?
Thanks
kvgr

Comment: Where your persistence.xml file located? Can you post its contents?

Comment: I figured it out, and problem was missing Hibernate Validator library...

Comment: if you've solved your own problem you can post your solution as an answer by clicking the outline of the checkmark next to it. This let's everyone know that it's been solved when they see it in the question list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good answer : you need to add the Hibernate Validator to your application.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the JPA annotations (such as @Id and @OneToMany) are either:

(1) All immediately above the fields.

```
@Id
public Long id;
```

(2) Or, All immediately above the getter for the fields.

```
private Long id;

@Id
public Long getId(){
    return id;
}
```

Using a combination will lead to the error you are seeing.

```
// ERROR

@Id
private Long id;

private List<Child> children;


public Long getId(){
    return id;
}

@OneToMany
public List<Child> getChildren(){
    return id;
}
```

Note that some annotations such as:

@Constraints.Required

@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")

etc...

must be immediately above the field name. You cannot put these above the getters. But that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, for adding the validator, add this to your dependencies.yml

## Application dependencies

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.9.Final:
        force: true
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-validator 4.2.0.Final
```